# Trying to generate 5000 datasets from N(0, 1) each with sample size n = 20

Tags: r

Have to generate 5000 datasets from N(0,1) with a samples size of 20. Need the datasets to run t-tests with different alphas.

`x=runif(20, min=0, max=1) x lapply(1:5000, x rnorm(n=20, mean=x, sd=sqrt(10)))`

This is what I have so far. I not sure how to set it so the range of data pieces is [0,1]

Comment: Not sure what you mean `range of data pieces is [0,1]`. In your example you are drawing from normal distribution with mean between 0 and 1, and sd= sqrt(10)

Comment: Do you want to draw from N(0,1), or from the uniform distribution?

Comment: N(0,1). Part of the question got cut off but I edited it

Comment: Instead of `lapply()` perhaps `replicate()` is a better option. Also you have some weird syntax that won't run. It looks like you're inserting `x` in places it shouldn't be.

Comment: If you want to draw from normal with mean 0 and sd=1, why do you call mean=x and sd=sqrt(10)?

Comment: I changed it to this lapply(1:5000, function(x) rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1), but it doesn't run anything

Comment: You're just missing a close paren. But the answer below is a cleaner way to get the same output, just add `simplify = F` so you get a `list` as your output.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the missing paren. I made "t.test(x, mu=mu0, alt="two.sided", lev=0.95)" for conducting t-tests and constructing CI intervals but Im not sure how to run a t-test using the data from the dataset from the lapply function

Comment: Post that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

5000 datasets, each a draw of size 20 from N(0,1) is just:

```
replicate(rnorm(n=20),n=5000)
```

Comment: And depending on the desired format of the output you can modify the `simplify` argument. E.g. set `simplify = F` to get a `list` instead of an `array`.